# For loop export to CSV with dynamic CSV naming

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, export-to-csv

I am relatively new to Python (most of my experience has been in SAS), so please bear with me.

I'm trying to create a number of CSVs from an existing dataset and export them based on a defined list. The naming of the CSVs should be dynamic based on the corresponding list value.

I've tried a lot of things - mostly stabbing in the dark - and nothing works. See code below

```
cc = ['AD-1','AD-2','AD-3'] #the list I want it to cycle through
for index in range(len(cc)): 
    df1_cc = df[df['charge'].isin(cc)] #df is predefined 
    #set "charge" as the index variable so you can aggregate on it           
    df1_cc = df1_cc.set_index('charge')
    df1_cc
    #sum up values based on individual values of 'charge'
    table1_cc = df1_cc.sum(level='charge')
    table1_cc
    #output to CSV
    table1_cc.to_csv(r"C:\Users\etc\table1_"+cc+".csv")
```

Note, the values in cc (AD-1, AD-2 and AD-3) are contained in 'charge' among others

The only error I get is here:

table1_cc.to_csv(r"C:\Users\etc\"+cc+".csv")

The error I get is:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

The output should be 3 files: table1_AD-1.csv, table1_AD-2.csv and table1_AD-3.csv, and each should contained summed values of each individually (again, that part works. The real issue is looping through and exporting to CSV the output for each individual value in cc).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Python! An "idiomatic" way to re-approach your loop would be to use the "in" operator directly on your list - cc.  eg: `for name_stub in cc:` then use `name_stub` where it is needed. This would be full "pythonista" style... but also, try enumerate as suggested below as well to give you an "`" style incrementing counter inside the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the last line of `to_csv`

```
cc = ['AD-1','AD-2','AD-3'] #the list I want it to cycle through
for index in range(len(cc)): 
    df1_cc = df[df['charge'].isin([cc[index]])] #df is predefined 
    #set "charge" as the index variable so you can aggregate on it           
    df1_cc = df1_cc.set_index('charge')
    df1_cc
    #sum up values based on individual values of 'charge'
    table1_cc = df1_cc.sum(level='charge')
    table1_cc
    #output to CSV
    table1_cc.to_csv(r"C:\Users\etc\table1_"+cc[index]+".csv")
```

Comment: This works - mostly! When I check the output, I get three correctly named CSV files. The problem is, each contains the following:


charge hrs
AD-1 2638
AD-2 2581
AD-3 246

Whereas the first should be:

charge hrs
AD-1 2638

The second should be:

charge hrs
AD-2 2581

And the last should be:

charge hrs
AD-3 246

Comment: thanks for updating. I'm getting this error:

TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

Comment: @ZDR adding [] in that line , check it again

Answer (score 0):

You could also iterate through your `cc` list like this:

```
cc_list = ['AD-1','AD-2','AD-3'] #the list I want it to cycle through

for index,cc in enumerate(cc_list): 
    df1_cc = df[df['charge'].isin([cc])] #df is predefined 
    #set "charge" as the index variable so you can aggregate on it           
    df1_cc = df1_cc.set_index('charge')
    df1_cc
    #sum up values based on individual values of 'charge'
    table1_cc = df1_cc.sum(level='charge')
    table1_cc
    #output to CSV
    table1_cc.to_csv(r"C:\Users\etc\table1_{}.csv".format(cc))
```

Comment: Thanks Nakor. Similar to my initial comment to above, it works but the output isn't quite right:

This works - mostly! When I check the output, I get three correctly named CSV files. The problem is, each contains the following: charge hrs AD-1 2638 AD-2 2581 AD-3 246 Whereas the first should be: charge hrs AD-1 2638 The second should be: charge hrs AD-2 2581 And the last should be: charge hrs AD-3 246